# VB Reading a text file into a 2D array?

Tags: vb.net, file-io, multidimensional-array, sudoku

I am trying to create a sudoku game, with load and save game functions in VB and I was wondering how it would be possible to load a save file(the numbers on the sudoku board and time score) and make the numbers within the file correspond to their exact location on the new board. For saving the file I have this:

```
Private Sub saveBoard(fileName As String)
    Dim f As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(fileName)
    For col = 0 To 8
        Dim sudokuLine = ""
        For row = 0 To 8
            If (board(row, col).Text = "") Then
                sudokuLine += "0"
            Else : sudokuLine += board(row, col).Text
            End If
            sudokuLine += " "
        Next
        f.WriteLine(sudokuLine)
    Next
    f.WriteLine(lblMinutes.Text + " " + lblSeconds.Text)
    f.Close()
End Sub
```

Also I know about StreamReader...

Comment: How is declared and initialized the board(x,y) array?

Comment: Private board(8, 8) As TextBox if that's what you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This could be the loadBoard that corresponds to your saveBoard.
Of course a bit of testing is required here and a more fool proof approach to handle critical errors (like a different file passed as input) .

Notice that I have added the [using statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx) around the opening of the Stream. This should be done also in the saveBoard above to avoid problems with files locked in case of exceptions.

```
Private Sub loadBoard(fileName As String)
    Using f = New StreamReader(fileName)
        For col = 0 To 8
            Dim sudokuColumn = f.ReadLine()
            Dim cells() = sudokuColum.Split()
            For row = 0 To 8
                If cells(row, col) = "0") Then
                    boards(row, col).Text = ""
                Else 
                    board(row, col).Text = cells(row,col)
                End If
            Next
        Next
        lblMinutes.Text = f.ReadLine()
    End Using

End Sub
```